# How to print the first word of a string in a specific column using awk

Tags: command-line, printing, awk

I have this output using **cat csvfile**:

```
Center_code       Name                    City_code
    800      SCHOOL NUMBER ONE              8000
    801      SCHOOL NUMBER TWO              8010
    802      INSTITUTE GALCERAN PINE        8020
    803      EASD PINE                      8030
    804      SCHOOL NUMBER THREE            8040
    805      INSTITUTE CAN CLOS             8050
    806      ESCRBC CAT                     8060
    807      SCHOOL NUMBER FOUR             8070
```

I want to print every name of the center (column 2) with awk, but using only the first word and without repeating them. The output is this:

```
SCHOOL
INSTITUTE
EASD
ESCRBC
```

Using another awk command, I want to count how many times does every word appear in column 2. The output is this:

```
SCHOOL  4
INSTITUTE  2
EASD  1
ESCRBC  1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: does this work: `awk '{print $2}' csvfile | sort | uniq -c` ?

Comment: Your text says "csv file" but what you have shown is a pretty-printed table. What is the actual format of your data?

Comment: okay, then please edit your question and use the output of `cat csvfile` instead of "as seen opening it with Excel". Then also, I can edit my answer to make it valid for your file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```bsh
awk 'NR>1{print $2}' csvfile | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
      1 EASD
      1 ESCRBC
      2 INSTITUTE
      4 SCHOOL
```

or `awk` only:

```bsh
awk 'NR>1{seen[$2]++} END{for (w in seen){printf "%s %s\n",w,seen[w];}}' csvfile
```

Output:

```
ESCRBC 1
SCHOOL 4
INSTITUTE 2
EASD 1
```

---

UPDATE:

For comma-separated file:

Try,

```
 awk -F, 'NR>1{split($2,arr," ");print arr[1]}' csvfile | sort | uniq -c
```

or `awk` only:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{split($2,arr," ");  seen[arr[1]]++} END{for (w in seen){printf "%s %s\n",w,seen[w];}}' csvfile
```

Comment: Sorry, but awk 'NR>1{print $2}' csvfile | sort | uniq -c doesn't work. I don't know what happen, but it prints another parts of the second column, and other fields of the csv file.

Comment: It prints the whole column 2 for every row. I need only the first word (EASD, ESCRBC, ...)

Comment: see my update, if you have a csv instead of the input you gave us in the Q

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Thank you very much!